# How to use multiple placeholders (?) in raw Laravel query with in closure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here is my code...

```
//Database:: find matching results in feeds table
$users_size = $this->holders($this->followed_users_id);
$slugs_size = $this->holders($this->followed_slugs_id);

$match_query = "select * from feeds " .
    "WHERE (user_id IN ($users_size)) " .
    "OR (target_id IN ($slugs_size) AND feedable_type = 'review') " .
    "ORDER BY created_at DESC;";

    $result = DB::select($match_query, $this->followed_users_id, $this->followed_slugs_id);
```

and don't worry about the (?) placeholders as they are dynamically generated as per requirements and $`this->followed_users_id` and `$this->followed_slugs_id` are arrays

Result is this

> QueryException in Connection.php line 655:
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from feeds WHERE (user_id IN (1,17)) OR (target_id IN (?,?) AND feedable_type = 'review') ORDER BY   created_at DESC;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bindings have to be in an array and as a second parameter in the `select` method

```
$bindings = array_merge($this->followed_users_id, $this->followed_slugs_id);

$result = DB::select($match_query, $bindings);
```

Comment: yup, got the solution... third parameter should not be there

Comment: $consolidatedArray = array_merge($this->followed_users_id, $this->followed_slugs_id);
    $results = DB::select($match_query, $consolidatedArray);